# Why are Online parallel quests not clearing?

Tags: dragon-ball-xenoverse

I'm doing some of the hard quests online, and looking for help *actually* clearing them. For some reason, after I complete them, they do not appear as cleared - I get a message saying "finished" and "clear", but on the results screen, I'm awarded with everything except the rank (eg exp., Zeni, etc). The rank stays black and is not awarded. I've tried different quests with several characters, including the hero, all of which ended with the same results. I try to always use the hero because I thought that that was preventing me from clearing the quests, but obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Does anybody knows why this is happening? Has this happened to anyone else?

For reference, I have already finished the main campaign (with the exception of the thing with the five time crystals/shards which I'm currently trying to get).

Comment: Do you still finish the quest ? Or dose the time run out ? Or when dose the result screen appear ? To get a clear you just need to do the 1 Main quest. For the ultimate clear you need both secret quests. If you fail the secret quest you still win because you finished the Main quest

Comment: I do finish the quests, sometimes even with an ultimate finish, the blue text of "finished" and "clear" appears, the thing is that it's not giving me any rank despite the fact that the quest is finished, in the description of the scores, it gives me the green "Quest clear", but it does not give any rank so it stays as "not clear"

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen to me as well. One thing I noticed is it always happens on quests I don't currently have unlocked for offline play. You can still join levels you don't have, because someone else made it. But you cant create an online parallel if you dont have access to it offline. However. Even still. I've found quests I do have, even i ngames i've created myself, still end up not getting cleared officially.

I have no definitive answer. If you find one, that would be great to know but so far I think a) it's a RNG problem. or B) someone else on your team didnt have the quest, thus, they didnt get a clear either, and so by default you are denied the clear.

Comment: Ok, so I don't think that option b) is the problem, yesterday I joined a quest which I have (not cleared) and it was only two of us, the host and me, in the end I did not get the clear rank and I already have the quest (it even says the score when I try it offline) and the host HAS to have the quest to create a game, right? So I'll just keep looking for something, and hoping that some of you guys have the answer, thanks.